# Can I tell if a hard drive is usable or fake?

Tags: macos, terminal, hard-drive, command-line, usb

I purchased a hard drive which looks like a fake (doesn’t mount when I plug it in, the label is suspicious).

If there a way using terminal to know if it’s usable? Nothing mounts when I plug it in Disk Utility [as seen in this screenshot](https://imgur.com/jvd2lOM).

[image]

[image]

The Terminal command returns this:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            1.0 TB     disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

Comment: It's either a bad cable, a defective SSD, or a fake.

Comment: You already know it's not useable :-) You could try a different computer, but if nothing works, return the SSD.

Comment: Plug it in how?  On a SATA bus?  It doesn't show up in the `System Information` utility?  It wouldn't mount unless it had a filesystem the Mac understood on it.

Comment: Yes SATA to USB-A. Nothing mounts so I'm assuming it's just an empty box?

Comment: It could be it was just not properly formatted

Comment: Please add a screenshot of Disk Utility with the drive plugged in, and the output of `diskutil list` as text.

Comment: @nohillside Just did! Thank you

Comment: So, the Mac doesn't see the device at all -> try different port, different cable, different computer. If nothing helps, return it.

Comment: @nohillside your comment probably qualifies as an answer. Unfortunately some ebay sellers are very skilled at waiting a while to ship the item, use a slow shipping process and then delete their account and product pages so you can't return anything - I was just intrigued by the hypothesis that it's just an SSD shaped case with nothing inside? I would have been fine if it had been 500Gb instead of 2Tb... a nicer kind of ripoff would have been acceptable lol

Comment: Honestly, the name alone (and the lack of any actual brand) shouts „fake“ (probably made to look like [this](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/internal-drives/wd-blue-sata-2-5-ssd?sku=WDS200T2B0A)). Sorry about that.

Comment: @nohillside thank you! Maybe make the sum of your comments (including this link) into an answer so I can accept it and we get brownie points?

Comment: Thanks. But reverting my own "on hold" vote for some brownie points for myself seems rather inappropriate :-)

Comment: @nohillside you voted to put the question on hold? I've done anything I could and I'm sure it could help other people if it stays open ‍♂️

Comment: I will not answer it, but feel free to answer it yourself based on the comment.

Comment: Thanks for not obscuring the second barcode - that sealed the nail on the coffin.

Comment: In addition to the typos on the label. 3 of them in the following sentence:

"WAENING: Product can be damageb by Electrostatlic discharge.(ESD)"

Comment: But they spelled [Hoofddorp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoofddorp) correctly @Scot

Comment: @bmike Impressive, and you have a point. Perhaps legit after all!  (Note to reader, and apologies to MicroMachine: nope)

Comment: Anyone interested in a really fun looking hard drive? It will entertain your friends and you'll be the life of the party 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening it up should let you  [see the circuit board](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/apple-nand-in-cheap-ssds)  and if it’s just parts and a cheap, small flash storage with firmware that intended to match the alleged size or if this is legit storage that has failed in some manner.

The label and branding present as suspicious to me. So if I had to guess, looks very counterfeit as it's trying to make you think it's a WD Blue SSD and the printing is very low budget. The case and connector are decent quality, but again, those are very inexpensive in bulk compared to a tested SSD NAND.

System profiler will enumerate the USB bus if that’s how you connect this as well as all SATA connections if you use that direct to the Mac. You should see those even if the storage layer like `diskutil` shows nothing.

That WWN should show to the sata controller, specifically.

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType
system_profiler SPSerialATADataType
system_profiler SPStorageDataType
```

However, you can use a barcode scanning app like [QRafter](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/qrafter-qr-code-reader/id416098700) and see the first two barcodes scan as the exact same sequence - Code 128 representing 1Z123X5603123458. The third doesn’t scan due to the fold I presume, but they all are the same barcode. So, someone didn’t even generate matching barcodes for the serial number, model number and WWN but manipulated the same image to alter the scale of each.

[image: Code 128 barcode of 1Z123X5603123458]